# pushViewController when back from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

When app is back from the background, I want to push my menu viewcontroller from the navigation controller.

To test — NSString returns the title of my Navigation controller so it should work, but it does not. 
It always show the view controller.

P.S. I use storyboard.

In `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{    

    NSString * test = self.window.rootViewController.title; // return title of navigation controller

    MenuViewController *mvc = [[MenuViewController alloc] init];
    [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:mvc animated:NO];
}
```

[Download Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3hcr8qu26rnjads/Archive1.zip)

Comment: You should keep a reference to the global UINavigationController in your AppDelegate when you do things like this.

Comment: Are you sure that the navigation controller is the rootViewController of the window?

Comment: Check self.window.rootViewController isn't nil.  If it isn't set by the end of `-applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` you usually get a compiler warning

Comment: When I check the NSString *test variable it has the same text as the title when I chose Navigation controller in storyboard so I suppose YES. Or how should I check that?

Comment: You probably don't want to push your menu but rather `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` to restart your app at the beginning.

Comment: [(UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; doesent do anything diferent. When I chance the push with pop I get the same view when I leave the app.

Comment: I add project to question description so you can test it.

Comment: Probably UINavigationController wasn't loaded fully.

Comment: Flink - how I can change that?

Comment: I think, you need to place your push method in viewDidAppear of your topViewController. And have some BOOL value in AppDelegate, that you can set when you are back from background, and check later in topViewController.

Comment: topViewController does not fire viewDidAppear method when I an back in app becouse it starts where it is ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you should update your UI in - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application method.

**Update.**

Also, error is because in your storyboard you present new ViewControllers as Modal, but you should Push them. Then you can return to main menu by calling

```
[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

To change presentation style choose segue in your storyboard, choose Attributes Inspector and change style to 'Push'.

Or, if you prefer Modal presentation style, call

```
[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! You save me lots of hours and nerves :)